# Can I B0re a decoy?

Tags: borderlands-2

> **B0re** is a tier 3 skill in [Zer0](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Zer0)'s [Sniping](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Sniping) skill tree. It allows his bullets to pierce through enemies, and grants massive bonus damage if the shot hits an enemy after piercing an enemy.

http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/B0re

> **Decepti0n** is [Zer0](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Zer0)'s [Action Skill](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Action_Skill). [...] He [...] deploys a holographic decoy [...].

http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Decepti0n

Can I shoot through my own decoy to get B0re bonus damage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, shooting through your own decoy grants bonus damage by B0re. I haven't tested it with others' decoys.

Comment: As a general tip, I might recommend trying another players B0re, the next time you play, and getting back to us on if it worked. It might also be helpful to users if you link to some more adamant proof. While I often accept "tried this myself" to be reliable, I suspect others do not agree.